# Swift 3 Beginner - Position Assets in Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I am a complete beginner at Swift 3 and programming in general so this will be an incredibly basic question.

I have been following tutorials and am currently positioning a SpriteNode using CGPoint. The tutorial recommends the following to position the Node centrally at the bottom of the screen:

```
Ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
```

However, that causes it to stick to the top-right of the screen.

When I use the following code:

```
Ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.frame.width / 2, y: 0 - self.frame.height / 2)
```

It positions at the bottom-centre as intended.

I do not understand why this happens as there is very little else done in the tutorial at this point to cause the error.

Comment: You should add more code to your question, it's too broad. What is the ground scale, the anchorPoint? The origin point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `anchorPoint` of the scene to the bottom left corner at the beginning of your `didMove(toView: SKView)` (or in `GameViewController`):

```
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Keep in mind that everything you place on the scene is placed based on the `anchorPoint`. So with this `anchorPoint`, the origin of your scene is the bottom left corner.

Also note that if you're using `.AspectFill` as your `sceneScaleMode`, you don't have to use `self.frame` and instead set the scene size to 768x1024 (portrait)/ 1024x768 (landscape) then just use number values within the scene size.

Additionally, there are advantages of setting your scenes `anchorPoint` to the centre:

`scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`

This makes it easier to fit the scene into iPad size as well as iPhone, and also simplifies centering nodes.

See this link for more info on making your app universal: [iOS Universal Device App with SpriteKit, how to scale nodes for all views?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34864533/6728196)

Comment: So, setting the anchorPoint globally gives me a lot more control, thanks. If I choose to remove .AspectFill and use exact values will this scale to different displays?

Comment: @MartinJones  Using .AspectFill is what scales the scene to fit all sizes. That's when you would use exact values, as it scales up to whatever size the device is. See this link for more: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34864533/6728196

Comment: Where and when do you set sceneScaleMode?

Comment: @Confused You can set it in both the GameViewController, and/or in each scene that you want it to affect. Try to call it before you do any placement in the scene as anything before it's called will not be affected by it.

Comment: Thank you. Having much "fun" dealing with iPad Pro 12.9 screen vs the other iPad sizes...

Comment: @Confused No problem. It can be quite the struggle when dealing with all the various sizes :)

Comment: So... if I'm understanding this right, setting to .AspectFill, I can use literal numbers in the range of 1024x768, and this should work the same on both the big iPad Pro and smaller iPads... right?

Comment: And, sorry, one more stupid question, where inside the gamescene's code do you set the .AspectFill? Inside didMoveToView?

Comment: @Confused Yes. However for iPads, the background should be at 1024x1024 and you will have to do some extra customization (as in the link from earlier). That means that the screen is just wider (or taller) than on iPhone and you would have to account for that

Comment: @Confused Try to set it as early as possible, so first thing in `didMove(toView: SKView)`. I also set the scene `anchorPoint` to `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` there too

Comment: Why square? 1024x1024? That doesn't make any sense to me. Surely the 3:2 ratio of 1024x768 makes more sense? But... I'm confused.

Comment: @Confused Setting it to square accounts for the wider screen... I'm not fully sure why, but it scales fine when the background is set to that. The scene size is still the 3:2 ratio, however the images that you want to be cut off on iPhone but fill iPad screen have to be 1024x1024

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense at all. To me. Are you talking about a background image, only, not the frame size as set in the scene editor?

Comment: @Confused Yes. When I say 1024x1024 I mean only for the background image. Sorry for the confusion. This way, the background doesn't get stretched to the bigger iPad size, and is rather sized fine for iPad and the sides (or top edges if in landscape) of the image are cut off for iPhone

Comment: Cheers. That makes some sense. Although it still feels like someone at Apple dropped the ball on thinking about responsiveness.

Comment: @Confused  I agree. Glad I could help

Comment: @Nik `This makes it easier to fit the scene into iPad size as well as iPhone` how do you figure?  Unless you are only referring to when using the `.ResizeFill` scale mode

Comment: @Nik also another reason, in < iOS 10, it doesn't require the SKCamera to be offset to correctly set the position

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm mostly referring to using .`ResizeFill`, but also I find that setting the `anchorPoint` to the centre of the frame allows for more simpler positioning when it comes to iPhone size vs iPad size as opposite side nodes would have coordinates that are negative of each other (e.g. 560, and -560). Also, this way you're building outwards from the centre rather than from the bottom left corner which varies in distance from other edges on iPhone and iPad

Comment: @Knight0fDragon As for your other comment, I'm not familiar with using SKCamera, so if that's an issue with my answer, feel free to edit it to your liking (or delete parts)

Comment: @Nik  that is what I was figuring,  (the .ResizeFill part)  The other scale modes do not matter in regards to iPhone and IPad since you are dealing with the same scene size,  and the cropping happens evenly on all sides

Comment: not an issue, an inclusion for a reason to use anchor at .5, .5  This is my preferred anchor point as well for coordinates,  I find it easier for everyone to understand because we are taught in school that center is origin