# SpriteKit scene size and image scale

Tags: ios, image, sprite-kit

I know SpriteKit require a size for SKScene and we can choose between iPhone screen size (SE/7/7+).
SE/7 and 7+ don't have the same screen scale (2x VS 3x), so what about all my SpriteNode textured with image, if I use a SE size for my SKScene. images will be blurred by the rescale 2x to 3x ?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34864533/6728196