# Create a container (fixed aspect ratio) for a landscape SpriteKit game, which can be played both on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I want to create a landscape iOS game with `SpriteKit`, which can be played both on iPhone and iPad. Because of the different aspect ratios I thought it would be usefull to have a fixed frame for the actual game. I would like to treat this game area like a separate container. The rest of the visible area should be filled with a ground, where the character is running on, and a ceiling. Depending on the device the ground and the ceiling will be more visible on the iPad and less on the iPhone.

The anchor point for the game as reference for all upcoming nodes should be in the lower left corner of the game area.
In the following picture I tried to draw my thoughts:

[image]

Can you tell me, what is the best way to proceed and which features of `SpriteKit` are worth to take a look at? I have never worked with `scaleModes` or something else like this before.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34864533/6728196

Comment: That is exactly what the .aspectFill scale mode does

Comment: You design your scene size to be a 4:3 ratio,  then on a 16:9, the excess will be cropped