# SpriteKit physics not matching image

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my Pong game, the ball is not properly bouncing. So, in the `View Controller`, I set the View's `showPhysics` to true, and this is the image I got:

[image]

These paddles have been resized in my code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Create sprites
    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
    player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode

    // Get labels
    enemyLabel = self.childNode(withName: "enemyScore") as! SKLabelNode
    playerLabel = self.childNode(withName: "playerScore") as! SKLabelNode

    // Set constraints
    setConstraints()

    // Screen border
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY - ball.frame.height * 2, width: frame.width, height: frame.height + ball.frame.height * 4))
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody = border

    // Reset game
    reset()

}
```

and my `setConstraints` function:

```
func setConstraints() {

    let enemyPositionY = SKConstraint.positionY(SKRange(constantValue: frame.maxY - 15))
    enemy.constraints = [enemyPositionY]
    enemy.size.width = frame.width / 4

    let playerPositionY = SKConstraint.positionY(SKRange(constantValue: frame.minY + 15))
    player.constraints = [playerPositionY]
    player.size.width = frame.width / 4

}
```

So from this, I can tell that when I resize my Sprite, the physics boundaries do not change. How can I fix this?

This is strange behaviour, but thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

The `Physics Definition` (all done in the Attributes Inspector):

[image]

.

**== EDIT (solution) ==**

Thank you. Now, I have created a function to reset the `physicsBody`:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

// Create new default physics body
func createPhysicsBody(for body: inout SKSpriteNode) {

    // Create new physics body
    body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: body.frame.size)
    body.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    body.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    body.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    body.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    body.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    body.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    body.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

}
```

And to call it, you use:

```
createPhysicsBody(for: &player)
```

**EDIT**

I have now moved on to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864533/ios-universal-device-app-with-spritekit-how-to-scale-nodes-for-all-views) which is a much easier way of doing the screen layouts.

Comment: put the code where you apply the physicsBody to the player in your question

Comment: @RonMyschuk I have added it in to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhysicsBodies are not dynamic. They will not change when you alter a SKSpriteNode. You will need to rethink how you create your physics bodies. You either will have to come up with a correct size in the editor and stick with it, or you will have to adjust the physicsBody rectangle after you adjust the size of the player in code.

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.frame.size)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will do that pragmatically as I need constraints

Comment: yup, unfortunately

Comment: I don't mind too much, it just really confused me at first 

Comment: Is there a way to just change the Body rather than creating a new object? Otherwise I have to reset every parameter (e.g. friction, rotation, all of it)

Comment: i'm pretty sure the code in my answer just changes the physicsBody not creating a new one

Comment: No, everything reset. The paddles were spinning when the ball hit it - absolute chaos

Comment: oh ya, lol...you have to reset the other parameters again. isDynamic etc.

Comment: I will make a function for that tomorrow, and will add it to my question.